# Why isn't the ListView saved to the memory?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my app. There is a ListView with custom objects and I want it to be saved in memory and to be able to add new things in it when the app is running. The thing is that I don't know how to save my ListView in memory and show it. Can you please help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String nume;
        String prenume;
        String email;
        String eticheta;
        int number;

        TextView addColegButton = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        ListView nume_ListView = findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        String nou = getString(R.string.nou);
        String addClassmate = getString(R.string.AddClassmate);

        TextView buna = findViewById(R.id.bunaTextView);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);


        if (hour >= 12 && hour <= 18) {
            buna.setText(R.string.bună);
            buna.setTextSize(43);
        }
        if (hour >= 18 && hour <= 24) {
            buna.setText(R.string.bunăSeara);
            buna.setTextSize(39);
        }
        if (hour >= 0 && hour <= 12) {
            buna.setText(R.string.bunăDimi);
            buna.setTextSize(36);
        }

        ArrayList<nume_list> colegi_list = DataHolder.getInstance().people;

        ColegListAdapter adapter1 = new ColegListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, colegi_list);
        nume_ListView.setAdapter(adapter1);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras == null) {
                nume = null;
                prenume = null;
                eticheta=null;
                email=null;
                number= 0;
            } else {
                nume = extras.getString("NumeFam");
                prenume = extras.getString("Prenume");
                email = extras.getString("Email");
                number = extras.getInt("Number");
                eticheta = extras.getString("Eticheta");
                String nume_complet = prenume + " " + nume;

                nume_list colegNou = new nume_list(nume_complet, eticheta, email, number);
                nume_list colegNouv2 = new nume_list(prenume, eticheta, email, number);

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container));

                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textToast);

                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0,50);
                toast.setView(layout);

                if (prenume != null && nume != null && eticheta != null) {
                    colegi_list.add(colegNou);
                    text.setText(R.string.toast1);
                    toast.show();
                }

                else if (nume == null && eticheta != null && prenume != null) {
                    colegi_list.add(colegNouv2);
                    text.setText(R.string.toast1);
                    toast.show();
                }

                else{
                    text.setText(R.string.toast2);
                    toast.show();
                }

            }
        } else {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Schoolbox", MODE_PRIVATE);

            nume = sharedPreferences.getString("NumeFam", "");
            prenume = sharedPreferences.getString("Prenume","");
            eticheta = sharedPreferences.getString("Eticheta","");
            email = sharedPreferences.getString("Email","");
            number =sharedPreferences.getInt("Number",0);

            String nume_complet = prenume + " " + nume;
            nume_list colegNou = new nume_list(nume_complet, eticheta, email, number);
            nume_list colegNouv2 = new nume_list(prenume, eticheta, email, number);

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container));

            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textToast);

            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0,50);
            toast.setView(layout);

            if (prenume != null && nume != null && eticheta != null) {
                colegi_list.add(colegNou);
                text.setText(R.string.toast1);
                toast.show();
            }

            else if (nume == null && eticheta != null && prenume != null) {
                colegi_list.add(colegNouv2);
                text.setText(R.string.toast1);
                toast.show();
            }

            else{
                text.setText(R.string.toast2);
                toast.show();
            }
        }

        addColegButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ColegInfoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this).toBundle());
            }
        });



        //TODO: Create the new classmate activity and set OnClickListener for the button to it.
    }
}
```

THE DETAILS ACTIVITY JAVA CODE (Where the details are added to a new object, later a new item in the ListView)

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(ColegInfoActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("Prenume", prenumeString);
                extras.putString("NumeFam", numeFamString);
                extras.putString("Eticheta",etichetaString);
                extras.putString("Email", emailString);
                extras.putInt("Number",number2);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Schoolbox", MODE_PRIVATE);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Prenume", prenumeString).apply();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("NumeFam", numeFamString).apply();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Eticheta",etichetaString).apply();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Email", emailString).apply();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("Number",number2).apply();
```

Comment: What do you mean with Listview saved to Memory? Do you mean something like a database, where your data will be saved, can be retrieved later or new data can be added?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Can you help me please?

Comment: There are many approaches, but this link shows you what android thinks you should use(ROOM Database) There is also a Codelabs for it https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Comment: Ok, I put the dependencies, but I don't get how to make it exactly. Could you please rewrite the code (for a piece of data)?

Comment: That can't be done within one class. You need to create the database, you need Entitys which are inserted into the database and you need DAO to access these data. How you define the Entitys and the DAO has to be done by you. You should do the codelabs, there you are shown how you do all this and retrieve the data later on

Comment: Ok. Thank you!